# Why does my code only produce a 0.000000 outcome?

Tags: c, printf, double

Here is the code I'm using,

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main () {
    /* variable definition: */
    double sidea, sideb, sidec;
    /* Prompt user for side a */
    printf("Enter length of side a of the triangle: \n"); // Input the base
    scanf("%f", &sidea);
    /* Prompt user for side b */
    printf("Enter the length of side b of the triangle: \n"); // Input the base
    scanf("%f", &sideb);
    /* Prompt user for side c */
    printf("Enter the length of side c of the triangle \n");
    scanf("%f", &sidec);
    // Calculate the Perimeter
    double perimeter=  (sidea + sideb + sidec);
    // Print the result
    printf("The perimeter is : %f \n", perimeter);
    return 0;
}
```

Input data:
4.6
7.5
5.8

I can't for the life of me figure out why any values used for input result in 0.000000. Using float seems to work just fine. What am I missing. Thanks!

Comment: Please review [Ask] and then edit your questions title to look more like an actual question.

Comment: Also, show the input data that causes your concern.

Comment: Thank you, my apologies.

Answer (score 1):

Use `%lf` format specifier for reading double.

Also you may note that using wrong format specifier is UB.(Undefined behavior).